# Modify regex to return all matched pairs

Tags: java, regex

I'm attempting to match on a substring and key value pair. For example, matching on the string :
`"\"a,b,c\",,\"$a = test1, $1 = test2, $2 = test2\",3\n"` a

should return

```
a test1
1 test2
2 test2
a
b
c
```

where

```
a test1
2 test2
```

is a Map and `a,b,c` are `List` of items.

Below code :

```
import javafx.util.Pair;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class KeyValuesExtract {

    private Pair<List<String>, Map<String, String>> getKeyValues(final String line) {

        final Pattern quotesPattern = Pattern.compile("\"(.*?)\"");
        final Matcher quotesMatcher = quotesPattern.matcher(line);
        quotesMatcher.find();

        final List<String> vids = Arrays.asList(quotesMatcher.group(0).split(",")).stream().map(x ->
                x.replace("\"", "").trim()).collect(Collectors.toList());

        final Map<String, String> enumKeyValuePairs = new HashMap<>();

        final Pattern keyValuePattern = Pattern.compile("\"\\$([A-Za-z0-9]+)\\s=\\s(\\w+)(?:,\\s\\$([A-Za-z0-9]+)\\s=\\s(\\w+))*\"");
        final Matcher keyValueMatcher = keyValuePattern.matcher(line);
        while (keyValueMatcher.find()) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= keyValueMatcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                enumKeyValuePairs.put(keyValueMatcher.group(i), keyValueMatcher.group(++i));
            }
        }

        return new Pair(vids, enumKeyValuePairs);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        final String str = "\"a,b,c\",,\"$a = test1, $1 = test2, $2 = test2\",3\n";

        final KeyValuesExtract testCode = new KeyValuesExtract();
        final Pair<List<String>, Map<String, String>> pair = testCode.getKeyValues(str);

        pair.getValue().entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
        });

        pair.getKey().forEach(entry -> {
            System.out.println(entry);
        });

    }

}
```

prints :

```
a test1
2 test2
a
b
c
```

From an earlier question : [Extracting key value pair from substring within string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68609154/extracting-key-value-pair-from-substring-within-string) I've updated the regex from

```
"\"\\$(\\d+)\\s=\\s(\\w+)(?:,\\s\\$(\\d+)\\s=\\s(\\w+))*\""
```

to match on both digits and characters :

```
"\"\\$([A-Za-z0-9]+)\\s=\\s(\\w+)(?:,\\s\\$([A-Za-z0-9]+)\\s=\\s(\\w+))*\""
```

How to match all the Map values ? :

```
a test1
1 test2
2 test2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use a single regular expression to capture multiple groups (see [Java regex: Repeating capturing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939526/java-regex-repeating-capturing-groups)).

Really, when your input become more complex you should use some [Lexer and Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50230053/java-lexer-and-parser).

Anyway, your problem can be solved iterating string twice:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
static class Result {
    private List<String> items;
    private Map<String, String> map;
}

static Result parse(String str) {
    final Result result = new Result(new ArrayList<>(), new HashMap<>());

    final Pattern find1 = Pattern.compile("(\" *\\p{Alnum}+ *(?:, *\\p{Alnum}+ *)*\")");
    final Pattern extract1 = Pattern.compile("\\p{Alnum}+");
    final Pattern find2 = Pattern.compile("(\" *\\$\\p{Alnum}+ *= *\\p{Alnum}+ *(?:, *\\$\\p{Alnum}+ *= *\\p{Alnum}+ *)*\")");
    final Pattern extract2 = Pattern.compile("\\$(\\p{Alnum}+) *= *(\\p{Alnum}+)");

    final Matcher matcher1 = find1.matcher(str);
    while (matcher1.find()) {
        final Matcher extractor1 = extract1.matcher(matcher1.group(0));
        while(extractor1.find())
            result.items.add(extractor1.group(0));
    }

    final Matcher matcher2 = find2.matcher(str);
    while (matcher2.find()) {
        final Matcher extractor2 = extract2.matcher(matcher2.group(0));
        while(extractor2.find())
            result.map.put(extractor2.group(1), extractor2.group(2));
    }

    return result;
}

public static void main(String... args) {

    // your example
    System.out.println(parse("\"a,b,c\",,\"$a = test1, $1 = test2, $2 = test2\",3\n"));

    // more complex case
    System.out.println(parse("\"a,b,c\",,\"$a = test1, $1 = test2, $2 = test2\",3,\"foo\",bar,\" $er33=33re  \"\n"));

}
```

with output

```
Result(items=[a, b, c], map={a=test1, 1=test2, 2=test2})
Result(items=[a, b, c, foo], map={a=test1, 1=test2, 2=test2, er33=33re})
```

or, if you need separate lists and maps you could do

```
private List<List<String>> items;
private List<Map<String, String>> map;
...
final Matcher matcher1 = find1.matcher(str);
while (matcher1.find()) {
    final Matcher extractor1 = extract1.matcher(matcher1.group(0));
    final List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
    while(extractor1.find())
        l.add(extractor1.group(0));
    result.items.add(l);
}

final Matcher matcher2 = find2.matcher(str);
while (matcher2.find()) {
    final Matcher extractor2 = extract2.matcher(matcher2.group(0));
    final Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<>();
    while(extractor2.find())
        m.put(extractor2.group(1), extractor2.group(2));
    result.map.add(m);
}
```

with output

```
Result(items=[[a, b, c]], map=[{a=test1, 1=test2, 2=test2}])
Result(items=[[a, b, c], [foo]], map=[{a=test1, 1=test2, 2=test2}, {er33=33re}])
```

Moreover, if you need to preserve the order you can also do it, with a regular expression `(find1|find2)` and then applying it to both `extract1` and `extract2`.

Comment: thanks for this, if a value for the contains an '_' , for example 'test2_5' :  System.out.println(parse("\"a,b,c\",,\"$a = test1, $1 = test2, $2 = test2_5\",3,\"foo\",bar,\" $er33=33re  \"\n")); then the pattern does not match. I could replace all _ prior to parsing,  can the regex be updated to handle this ?

Comment: Of course, you can replace `\\p{Alnum}` by any expression you would to match. E.g. `[_\\p{Alnum}]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex :

```
\$[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s*=\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]+[,]*
```

I tried with your example in `https://regex101.com/r/xDX5v7/1` :

```
"\"a,b,c\",,\"$a = test1, $1 = test2, $2 = test2\",3\n"
```

and it returned :

```
$a = test1,
$1 = test2,
$2 = test2
```

Once you have matched the regex pattern, you can use `.groupCount` method from `Matcher` class to get the counts, and then use space as a string delimiter to split the matched strings and put them in a map.